# How to get the name of textarea inside a jTabbedpane?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, tabs, jtabbedpane

In my programe, i dynamically generates a new textarea ta and renames it with a unique identifier(in my case it is tabidis)

```
            JScrollPane panel2 = new JScrollPane();
            panel2.setName(tabidis);

            ta = new JTextArea("");
            ta.setColumns(30);
            ta.setRows(20);
            ta.setEditable(false);
            panel2.setViewportView(ta);
            ta.setName(tabidis);

            jTabbedPane1.add(username4, panel2);
```

The element ta is generated dynamically and it given the respective name accordingly.

I need a method to get the name of "ta" withrespect to the tab selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot will depend on the structure of the UI, if it's consistent, then it becomes easier, if not, more difficult..

You could use something similar to this to find all the child components of a given type starting from a given parent component

```
public static <T extends Component> List<T> findAllChildren(JComponent component, Class<T> clazz) {
    List<T> lstChildren = new ArrayList<T>(5);
    for (Component comp : component.getComponents()) {
        if (clazz.isInstance(comp)) {
            lstChildren.add((T) comp);
        } else if (comp instanceof JComponent) {
            lstChildren.addAll(findAllChildren((JComponent) comp, clazz));
        }
    }

    return Collections.unmodifiableList(lstChildren);
}
```

This will return a `List` of the child components of specific type

Something like...

```
List<JTextArea> areas = findAllChildren(jTabbedPane1.getSelectedComponent(), JTextArea.class);
if (areas.size() > 0) {
    JTextArea ta = areas.get(0);
    String name = ta.getName();
}
```

Comment: The jTabbedPane1 contains only one element,ie ta. I want a method to get the name of ta (which i set dynamically unique to all the textareas) in the selected tab. Are there any easy ways .

Comment: Saw this code :   

sendto = ((JTextArea) jTabbedPane1.getSelectedComponent()).getName();

But it is not working .Error : jTabbedpanel1 cannot be cast.

Comment: Actually, you `jTabbedPane1` contains 4 components.  The component acting as the view for the tab, the scroll pane, the view port and your text area.  You could use `jTabbedPane1.getSelectedComponent().getComponent(0).getComponent(0)` which "should" return the text area....

Comment: In your code ".getComponent(0)" . I get this as an error. It is telling that cannot find symbol.

Comment: So I guess, no, there's not a simpler solution, unless you call `((JComponent)((JComponent)((JComponent)tp.getComponent(0)).getComponent(0)).getComponent(0)).getComponent(0)` simpler :P

Comment: did u mean .getcomponentAt(index) because .getComponent(0) is not working in netbeans

Comment: Nope. `getComponent` is a method of `Container`, `JComponent` is a type of `Container`, there fore you need to cast `Container` or a child of it, like `JComponent`. `Component` isn't a type of `Container`.  And the code I present was written in Netbeans (and run).  I don't believe there is a `getComponentAt` method for `JComponent`, that's a method of `JTabbedPane`

Comment: String taname=( jTabbedPane1.getSelectedComponent().getComponentAt(0,0)).getName();

The following code gave me the correct value. The value i wanted.

Comment: @madprogramer : can you please solve me this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17427583/how-to-check-if-the-tab-selected-is-changed-in-java

Comment: getComponentAt(int, int) is not the appropriate method to use, it relies of the position of the component, which can change between look and feels and will not work if you add more components to the component