# How to check if the tab selected is changed in java

Tags: java, events, netbeans, jtabbedpane

As far as i have seen the event:

```
(1)     private void jTabbedPane1StateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {}
```

Checks whether a new tab is added or an exiting tab is deleted or not.

On googling ,  i found this code:

```
(2)     ChangeListener changeListener = new ChangeListener() {
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent changeEvent) {
        // my code       
        }
        };
        jTabbedPane1.addChangeListener(changeListener);
```

I guess since it uses stateChanged event , it should do what the same a my first code.
By t way even after using both the codes i could not get the required resuts(ie An event that could be invoked when user changes the tab).

Can anyone suggest me a good event [i am using netbeans GUI environment] for effective action. (I dont want any mouseEvents)

**Edit:**

I want the following code to be excecuted if the tab changes:

```
String send3=( jTabbedPane1.getSelectedComponent().getComponentAt(0,0)).getName();
```

The above code dynamically gets the name of jTextarea (in the current tab) which is created dynamically in the jTabbedPanel.

Comment: i was thinking like using jTabbedPanel1.getSelected()==0...if else if case ,but since i have cant predict the number of tabs, i cant use this . But can anyone suggest me something similar to this

Comment: `ChangeListener` is the correct listener. Can you provide more code?

Comment: @johnchen902 Provided what i want

Comment: I will add `System.out.println("Something");` to `stateChanged` to see if `stateChanged` is really invoked. Please also see [**SSCCE**](http://sscce.org/) to learn how to ask a good question here.

Comment: @johnchen902 I am really sorry if, this question sounds false.My problem here is when i click on new tab,the first tab is created and  the state Change event works. When i click for the second tab, then also the statechange event works, But when i come back to the 1st tab and call the getName() (i menthioned in my code )function, it still returns me with the second tabs output.

Comment: I am not Jon Skeet, I can't find the problem without code.

Comment: ok @johnchen902 you where right. Thank you for the comment .But the Problem i face is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431755/using-jtextarea-with-jtabbedpanel

Comment: Don't use getComponentAt, it will not produce a reliable result, it could return the scroll pane or viewport of any of the components have any kind of padding or there offsets are changed

Answer (score 0):

I just checked my own source code where addChangeListener() works fine. The event is fired whenever the tab is changed by the user or programatically. In `stateChanged()` itself, the now selected tab is determined by

```
 JTabbedPane p = (JTabbedPane)e.getSource();
 int idx = p.getSelectedIndex();
```