# Using JTextarea with JTabbedPanel

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea, jtabbedpane

JTextarea is dynamically created and added to the jTabbed panel using the code:

```
            // tabidis is a variable with unique value in each case

            JScrollPane panel2 = new JScrollPane();
            panel2.setName(tabidis);

            ta = new JTextArea("");
            ta.setColumns(30);
            ta.setRows(20);
            ta.setEditable(false);
            panel2.setViewportView(ta);
            ta.setName(tabidis);

            jTabbedPane1.add(username4, panel2);
```

When new tabs are added (ta textarea is added along with it), the last tabs textarea recieves all the text.

```
 private void jTabbedPane1StateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt){
                send3 = ta.getName();
                ta.setName(send3);
                ta.setText(ta.getText()+send3);
                }
```

In the above code you can see that The text in both the textareas(In two tabs) should be updated. But what really happens is that only the second TextArea is getting updated.The first TextArea is not updated.

Comment: i don't understand `ta` value is always ONE , should be updated only one cause you are updating only one, you may want a `Collection` of textArea..

Comment: Why do you expect with this code, that two text areas should be updated? You are updating only ta which is just 1 text field. You are "reinitializing" the same textarea again and again. So last initialized textarea gets the text.

Comment: @Optional is there any way to put text to the textarea in the current tab ?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

`ta` only have a value at a time, what you need is a `Collection` of `TextArea` you have to have a reference to them for example in a `List<JTextArea> textAreas`

Then in your code

```
        JTextArea ta = new JTextArea("");
        ta.setColumns(30);
        ta.setRows(20);
        ta.setEditable(false);
        textAreas.add(ta);
```

And in your event something like this:

```
private void jTabbedPane1StateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt){
                for(JTextArea ta : textAreas ){
                 send3 = ta.getName(); // this line an below are redundant
                 ta.setName(send3);
                 ta.setText(ta.getText()+send3);
               }
}
```

Comment: sorry.. @nachokk i see the part :  for(JTextArea ta : textAreas ){ gives  me an error (cannot find local variable )

Comment: @user2471839 you should declare as a global variable in your class, scope all the class something like this `private List<JTextArea> textAreas =  new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Sorry the... above code does not work as i needed.Any other solution for this ?

Comment: @user2471839 what do you need? May be if you are more clear in your question we can help

Comment: i need to put the text in the textarea of the selected tab . The problem is that, when second textarea gets activated, tbe text goes into the seconde textarea

Comment: You want all the text in others tabs be shown in the selected tab?

Comment: No.Actually the text for the all the textAreas are drawn from the database. (it is actually a chat app)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32774/discussion-between-user2471839-and-nachokk)